# Betweenness of a vertex and edge in a graph

Tags: r, igraph

I created a graph using a code

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
```

and then used `betweenness` function which outputted value `8` for every vertex and `12.5` for every edge. However, what I have understood this function does, according to me answer must be `7` for every vertex .

Can someone explain me how is it `8` and for edge `12.5`?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following graph:

```
str(g)
# IGRAPH U--- 10 10 -- Ring graph
# + attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/l), circular (g/l)
# + edges:
#  [1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 5-- 6 6-- 7 7-- 8 8-- 9 9--10 1--10
```

Let's take vertex `2`, it appears on eight shortest paths:

```
1-2-3
1-2-3-4
1-2-3-4-5
1-2-3-4-5-6 (non-unique, 1-10-9-8-7-6)
3-2-1-10-9-8 (non-unique, 3-4-5-6-7-8)
3-2-1-10-9
3-2-1-10
4-3-2-1-10-9 (non-unique, 4-5-6-7-8-9)
4-3-2-1-10
5-4-3-2-1-10 (non-unique, 5-6-7-8-9-10)
```

So this is altogether `6` unique shortest paths, and four that each count as `1/2`, as there is one alternative path without `2` for each. This is `6` plus `2`, which is `8`.